# How to start a thread with Dispatcher

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I am writing a code for Folder Browser Application on WPF, I wrote a code to get the folders using expend button, and wrote a function to calculate the size of the folders, now it looks like this [Example of what am I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDNNp.png)

This is the main part of the code:
This is my item_Expanded method:

```
void item_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
        if (this.HasDummy(item))
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
            this.RemoveDummy(item);
            this.ExploreDirectories(item);
            this.ExploreFiles(item);
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
    }
```

it calls ExploreDirectories method:

```
private void ExploreDirectories(TreeViewItem item)
    {
        var directoryInfo = (DirectoryInfo)item.Tag;           
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            var isHidden = (directory.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden;
            var isSystem = (directory.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System;
            if (!isHidden && !isSystem)
            {
                item.Items.Add(this.GetItem(directory));
            }
        }
    }
```

it calls GetItem method:

```
private TreeViewItem GetItem(DirectoryInfo directory)
        {
            var item = new TreeViewItem
            {
                Header = $"Name: {directory.Name} \t Size: {ConvertSize(GetDirectorySize(directory))}",
                DataContext = directory,
                Tag = directory
            };
            this.AddDummy(item);
            item.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(item_Expanded);
            return item;
        }
```

and finaly it calls GetDirectorySize method:

```
static long GetDirectorySize(DirectoryInfo root, bool recursive = true)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = null;
            DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
            var startDirectorySize = default(long);
            {
                files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
            }     
            if (files != null)
            {                
                foreach (var fileInfo in files)
                    Interlocked.Add(ref startDirectorySize, fileInfo.Length);
            }           
            if (recursive)
            {
                    subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
                    Parallel.ForEach(subDirs, (subDirectory) =>
                    Interlocked.Add(ref startDirectorySize, GetDirectorySize(subDirectory, 
                    recursive)));

            }
            return startDirectorySize;
        }
```

How should I rewrite my code to use a Dispatcher, so it stops freezing while calculating the  size or expanding the folders and files? Should I rewrite my GetDirectorySize method, and change the Parallel.ForEach(), and Interlock.Add("recursive call here")?

Comment: First of all, your code should not create TreeViewItems directly, but only a hierarchical data structure to which a TreeView can be bound in XAML. You could then create the whole hierarchy or parts of it in a background thread, e.g. by using `Task.Run`. After awaiting a Task.Run call, add the created hierarchy to the collection to which the TreeView is bound. This would not need a Dispatcher call, since it would be done in the UI thread.

Comment: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: Hi, did U mean, that I have to write smth like a tree structure with nodes? Also, thanks for answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Take a look at HierarchicalDataTemplate, which is used with TreeViews.